# Tools for Javascript animations

Tags: javascript, animation, ide

Are there any editors or tools, similar to flash, which can generate animations in javascript ?

Comment: What your refering to is a framework. I wanted a tool by which the code is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple animations can be done in jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

**[jQuery Transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)** is a simple and effective tool for animations in JS. Its **Open Source** and available on GitHub : https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit

**PS**: I know you asked for a tool but I showed you a framework in jQuery Transit. But the framework is so easy that its faster to code in this than to use a tool :P

Answer (score 2):

[**Sencha Animator**](http://www.sencha.com/products/animator/). If you like Sencha (which I don't). It's [commercially licensed](http://www.sencha.com/products/animator/license/),  though.

Also, **Apple Keynote** can export it's magically animated goodness into HTML with CSS3 animations. Not open source of course.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard of [Edge](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/) but I've never personally tried it. You could give it a shot. Isn't open source, but it's made for HTML5, unlike Flash.